# Django How to Retrieve Data using POST and returned the data with serializer

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

How to use POST to retrieve single data on models?

My idea, at the beginning, was to pass a map of parameters. Then the view, on the server side, would take care of reading the needed parameters in the map and return the response.

When I tested this in Postman, I send request body with email and password, but then it returns an error: 'name is required'

I want this api to work like generics. Retrieve but not with url, but with POST instead

Models.py

```
class Member(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  password = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
  phone = models.IntegerField(default=9999)
```

serializer.py

```
class LoginMemberSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
    model = Member
    fields =[
        'name',
        'password',
        'email',
        'phone',
    ]
```

view.py

```
class LoginMemberAPI(APIView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Member.objects.all()

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = LoginMemberSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            print(serializer.validated_data['email'])
            member = Member.objects.get(name = str(serializer.validated_data['name']))
            # serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors)
```

[image: Example from my postman]

Comment: can you show the data that you are posting in the postman

Comment: you send `username` but in the model `name`?

Comment: @Exprator thanks, i edited it

Comment: @BearBrown sorry i mean email and password

Comment: Have you tried checking the checkbox on the row of the `name` key?

Comment: @ikkuh yes, if i check it, the response will return '{
    "email": [
        "member with this email already exists."
    ]
}
'

Answer (score 0):

Well, indeed the serializer is not valid, as it is supposed to be a complete representation of a model and you're only sending a single field.

It doesn't really make sense to use a serializer for this. Just use the data to query the db and *then* create a serializer for the response:

```
member = Member.objects.get(**request.POST)
serializer = LoginMemberSerializer(member)
return Response(serializer.data)
```

I would say, the fact that you are struggling with this should be able indication that this isn't the right thing to do. POST is meant for sending data that updates the db, not for retrieving data.

Comment: i get error 'Member matching query does not exist.' even when im just sending name only in postman.

if this wrong, what is the best solution for this case? i cant think of any solution for this. because my partner can achieve this with PHP CI, maybe this case can work with django too

Answer (score 0):

Your serializer is using fields of Model and in your 'Member' model, all fields are required. You can not do this with same Serializer. You can create separate serializers for validation and for returning serialized response. Something like this. 
Serializer for response:

```
class MemberSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Member
        # '__all__' will include all fields of models
        fields = '__all__'
```

Serializer for validation of this Api:

```
class LoginMemberSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Member
        fields =[
             'name',
             'password',
             ]
```

Comment: i changed the serializer and changed the view from top answer but stil get error Member matching query does not exist. w

Comment: " Member matching query does not exist." means that you don't have record in table for given query/filter. Make sure that the record you are trying to fetch is present in db.